# How get data from fragment and transfer it to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have recyclerView class. There are information that I have to display in fragments. For example: recyclerView contains : id, name, surname. How can i do that id list will displayed in the first fragment, then I click on item id and in the second fragment I get name and surname of this id?

my recyclerView class:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Source> sources;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
       final Source source = sources.get(position);
        holder.sourceId.setText(source.getId());
        holder.sourceName.setText(source.getName);
        holder.sourceSurname.setText(source.getSurname);
      }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sources.size();
    }

    public  class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView sourceName, sourceId, sourceSurname;
        public NewsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            sourceName = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
            sourceId = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceId);
            sourceDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceSurname);
        
            sourceId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

          bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceName.getText().toString());
          bundle.putString("sourceSurname", sourceSurname.getText().toString());
          NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
            newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, newsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Item clicked. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

my first fragment (where I have to display id only):

```
public class IdFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_fragment, container, false);
        restClient.startRetrofit();
        loadJSON();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
        return view;

    }

    private void loadJSON() {
        final Call<News> news = restClient.getApiInterface().getNews();
        news.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
                List<Source> sources = response.body().getSources();

                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), sources);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
           
            }
        });
```

and my second fragment (where I have to go after item click on the first fragment):

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
        TextView textView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.sourceSurname);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
       String sourceName = bundle.getString("sourceName");
          textView1.setText(sourceName);
      String sourceSurname = bundle.getString("sourceSurname");
          textView2.setText(sourceSurname);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily handle it.

Something that I have employed for this matter is using fragment constructor like below

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
    String param1,param2;
    public NewsFragment(String param1, String param2)
    {
        this.param1=param1;this.param2=param2;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....
        return view;
    }
}
```

When you set a constructor for your fragment then it will force you to feed parameters when you want to use it.

There is other approach too but something that I found the best approach is using fragment constructor.

Comment: what I have to transfer to this line:  `NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();` ?

Comment: @Monica `NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment(param1,param2);`

Comment: maybe I do something wrong,  it doesn't' work. In Fragment class: `public NewsFragment(String sourceNameItem) {
        this.sourceNameItem = sourceNameItem;
    }` `String sourceNameItem = bundle.getString("sourceName");` in adapter class:  `NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment(sourceNameItem);`

Comment: it was my mistake. I did wrong xml layout for fragments. now it is ok. Thank you for advice.